# Não reconhece um elemento do ListView

Tags: android

Estou criando um evento de *click*, para quando for pressionado um determinado `LinearLayout` que fica em uma `ListView`. Os atributos deste `ListView` ficam em um XML (`item_list`), porém não esta conseguindo buscar o linear para fazer o evento, esta dando `NullPointerException`.

```
    ...
    listView.setAdapter(adapterListView);
    beber = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.item_beber);
    beber.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            beberCerveja();
        }
    });
```

O erro ocorre na linha 2º linha.

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema, bastou fazer o evento de clique no AdapterListView.

Comment: Se eu bem entendi, esse `LinearLayout` está dentro de um item desta `ListView`, certo? Sendo assim, você somente conseguirá buscar o `item_beber` para definir o clique de dentro do seu `adapterListView`, que provavelmente é uma classe que estende de um `ArrayAdapter`.

Comment: 2º linha pra mim é `beber = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.item_beber);` e isso não implica em ter que fazer o evento em outro lugar, e implica apenas em não poder localizar o ID no seu contexto, você pode utilizar namespace para fazer isto sem ter que mudar nada :)

Comment: Funcionou colocando no AdapterListView, mas essa questão do namespace eu não entendi, poderia me explicar melhor?

Answer (score 2):

Utilize o método setOnItemClickListener()

```
listView.setAdapter(adapterListView);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new View.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        beberCerveja();
    }
});
```